# Is there a way to reorder Windows 11 taskbar's preview windows?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

In Windows 10 I used 7+ Taskbar Tweaker to be able to reoder windows's taskbar preview windows with a drag and drop.

It is very useful when you have multiple monitors and to organize my workflow.

Is there a way to do that with windows 11 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Taskbar Thumbnail Reorder](https://windhawk.net/mods/taskbar-thumbnail-reorder) Windhawk mod.

First, download and install Windhawk from https://windhawk.net/. Then, go to "Mods" at the upper right, search for "Taskbar Thumbnail Reorder" and install it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Focus the application window you want to be at the rightmost position in the previews.
2. Continue focusing each of the other windows of the application in sequence according to the desired order, right to left.
   **ⓘ** The application window you focus first in the sequence will be at the rightmost position, and the window you focus last will be at the leftmost position.
   **ⓘ** If you would like a visual overview of the order you have prepared, press the <kbd>**Windows key**</kbd>+<kbd>**Tab**</kbd> keyboard shortcut.
3. Open Windows [**Task Manager**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/how-to-run-task-manager-on-windows-11-6-ways/m-p/2701239).
4. Select "**Details**" from the navigation panel on the left side of the window.
5. Find `explorer.exe` in the list of processes. Click on it.
6. Click on "**Restart task**" on the "**Details**" toolbar:
   [image: Task Manager screenshot|674x584, 50%]

The Windows Taskbar will disappear momentarily and then reappear. You will now find that the taskbar previews for the application are in your preferred order.